# How Get height of the Status Bar and Soft Key Buttons Bar?

Tags: android, statusbar, softkeys

Is there a way in Android to get the size of the soft buttons bar and status bar togheter? or a way to go get the screen height without the height of both these bars? (they are not always the same, look at the nexus 7 for example)

Answer (score 2):

for me, in android note 10, I need to get navigation bar height by dimen:

```
fun getSoftNavigationBarSize(resources: Resources): Int {
    var result = 0
    val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This gives a warning:  "Using internal inset dimension resource navigation_bar_height is not supported".  Has this been deprecated, or is there another way to do this now?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered already, but I just found this solution that seems easier than the others. I only tried it for the bottom button bar. I'm pretty sure that it works the same way for the status bar though.

```
view.rootWindowInsets?.let { inset ->
    Log.e("XXX", "button bar height: ${inset.systemWindowInsetBottom}")
}
```

Note: you need a view that is attached to the window at this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void getStatusAndNavigationBarsHeight() {
        float deviceDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float statusHeight = 0;
        float navigationHeight = 0;
        Resources myResources = getApplicationContext().getResources();

        int idStatusBarHeight = myResources.getIdentifier( "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        statusHeight = idStatusBarHeight > 0 ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(idStatusBarHeight)/deviceDensity : 0;
        statusHeight = Math.round(statusHeight);
        Log.d("StatusBar Height(dp):", String.valueOf(statusHeight));

        int idNavigationBarHeight = myResources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        navigationHeight = idNavigationBarHeight > 0 ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(idNavigationBarHeight)/deviceDensity : 0;
        navigationHeight = Math.round(navigationHeight);
        Log.d("Navigation Bar Height(dp):", String.valueOf(navigationHeight));
    }
```

Comment: StatusBar Height(dp) : 33
Navigation Bar Height(dp): 48

Comment: statusHeight = idStatusBarHeight > 0 ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(idStatusBarHeight)/deviceDensity : 0;
navigationHeight = idNavigationBarHeight > 0 ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(idNavigationBarHeight)/deviceDensity : 0;

Comment: Here we are dividing by deviceDensity so the values returned looks more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more way to @Adrian Cid Almaguer's answer as I wanted to get status-bar height in background service.

```
val windowService = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)
(windowService as WindowManager).apply {
   val statusBar = currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
   val statusBarHeight = statusBar.top
}
```

And using the same method you can get Navigation Bar position, height, or width as well. (width if Navigation Bar is on the side of the screen)

```
var navBarHeight = 0
val navBar = currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
when {
  (navBar.bottom > 0) -> navBarHeight = navBar.buttom
  (navBar.right > 0) -> navBarHeight = navBar.right 
  (navBar.left > 0) -> navBarHeight = navBar.left 
 }
```

Comment: Hello @Divyang M, you are not mentioning that currentWindowMetrics requires SDK 30, so this solution is not applicable to older Android versions.