# Android Lollipop Design Issue

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have a `RelativeLayout` with height parameter `match_parent` and in this I have another `LinearLayout` with property `layout_alignParentBottom=true`.

I am using this layout to show `MediaController` buttons.

Below is what I am expecting to have in `MediaController`

[image]

But below is what I am getting on `Lollipop 5.1` (I have just added hard coded bottom margin to the layout, which is not at all any solution as it will not work well on all devices.)

[image]

**The layout hides behind the bottom back button bar**.

What will be the best way to only provide the necessary margin from bottom according to height of bottom bar as this layout works fine in other Android versions and earlier Android phones with Hardware back buttons.

> My XML file looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mypack.MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLinear"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumArt"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/default_cover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleOfSong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Title Of Song"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/albumOfSong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Album Of Song"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistOfSong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Artist Of Song"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genreOfSong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Genre Of Song"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> App Theme

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, the button bar isn't part of the normal screen, and align parent bottom isnt affected by this. Are you sure you don't have a negative bottom margin or similar? Or maybe the container over the player is pushing it out of the screen?

Comment: @breakline Well these days I am facing issues that are weird. Yes I am sure No negative margin or similar. I have posted my XML file.

Comment: Did you try layout_gravity -> center? Btw post the complete xml with the all components, its easier to analyse the your problem.

Comment: @Xplouder I posted the complete XML file. Gravity Center? Why I need to show it at bottom.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Angie Nopes. Just have provided hard coded margin bottom till now. If I get a solution I will post it here. If you get you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Activity is somehow using transparent navigation bar theme or something similar that allows to render view outside of the visible area.

Maybe giving some context about your Activity will help to figure out what is exactly happening.

That being said, you should use this attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows` in the root of your XML layout to force views to render only in the visible area of the window.

Comment: I just added `context` in XML mentioned in question. Also I tried to give `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to root element but no luck.

Comment: @gprathour I wasn't talking about `tools:context` but the style/theme/configuration of the Activity holding this view (`MyActivity`)

Comment: Just added theme of application to question. Is it what you asked for?

Comment: Yes, but the Activity configuration would be a plus. Are you setting visibility flags to the Activity decor view ? Or doing things like https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html ?

Comment: I have just added `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` apart from it nothing like that. Where can I find Activity Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything else the same and just add a bottom margin, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398929/how-get-height-of-the-status-bar-and-soft-key-buttons-bar?answertab=active#tab-top) describes a way to get the height of the bottom soft key bar by subtracting getRealMetrics() and getMetrics() and using the difference to imply the height dimension.

Not tested the method myself, but the feedback seems positive.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks. I have gone through such options but was wondering if we could find out why such thing is happening and any genuine way to solve this issue, not just a hack.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the line where you said that you'd hard-coded the margin already. Could you share the styles that you're using? As it feels to me like it's behaving in the same way as overlay mode for the action bar, just on the bottom. There may be a clue as to why in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defaultDisplay height and width in your Layout like this :
For you it's RelativeLayout params.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) yourUI.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
    params.leftMargin = 0;
    yourUI.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting programmatically the layout height equals the display height.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;
int statusBarHeight = 0;
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
      statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
RelativeLayout relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = height - statusBarHeight;
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @gprathour try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.