# What is size of softkey height of android "LG G4" smartphone?

Tags: android, smartphone

I'm trying to draw a activity screen on "LG G4" phone excepting bottom softkey height,

so spent several hours to find a screen specs in google, but I couldn't find.

How long is softkey height by pixel?

Comment: Did you look into this answer?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398929/how-get-height-of-the-status-bar-and-soft-key-buttons-bar

Comment: Thanks GaborNovak. :D  Your answer helped for me.